# Prove that the eigenvalues of the Legendre equation are integers

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The Legendre equation, $$\frac{d}{dx}((1-x^2)y') + \lambda y = 0$$ is an irregular Sturm-Liouville problem with $p(x) = 1 - x^2$, so that -1 and 1 are its singular points. I have been trying since yesterday to prove that its eigenvalues are necessarily integers without any kind of success. How can one prove it?

Comment: Don't you think that you need some boundary conditions?

Comment: @313 Well, as far as I know in irregural Sturm liouville problems we assume that the answer function, $f(x)$ and its derivative, $f'(x)$ are finite at the singularity points.

Comment: I meant in addition you probably should have some prescribed values of $y$ on the boundary of your domain (where you want to solve the eqn.)

Comment: These two ARE boundary conditions, and apparently they should suffice to determine the solution uniquely.

Comment: I doubt it. $ \ \ $

Comment: But the domain itself is $(-1,1)$, no furthur condition can be exposed on them!

Comment: The solution being finite at the singular points is enough to establish the family of solutions but not a unique solution.

Comment: @Cameron Williams so it must be enough to determine the eigenvalues, or am I wrong?

Comment: A common technique is power series methods and requiring that the series terminates (in order to assure proper convergence). One does this for the harmonic oscillator to get the eigenvalues are integral, for instance.

Comment: @313 The boundary conditions here are $|y(-1)|<\infty$ and $|y(1)|<\infty$.